# Visual Studio Intellisense error in range-based for loop

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2015

My Visual Studio 2015 IDE (Community Edition) keeps complaining about the code below

```
struct item
{
    int data;
    std::vector<item*> linkedItems;
};

void traverseLinkedItems(item* p_item)
{
    for (item* i : p_item->linkedItems) // Intellisense Error: A value of type "item*" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "item*"
    {
        std::cout << i->data;
    }
}
```

It compiles just fine. So I'm not sure whether it's a bug in VS, or am I missing something?
When I use auto instead of specifying the type of i explicitly, everything is OK.

Thanks!

Comment: When you use `auto i`, what does the tooltip say when you hover over `i`?

Comment: Does this still happen if you change the names of `data` and `item`?

Comment: @david Changing the names did not help. This is what the tooltip says:

typedef item *std::_Simple_types<item *>::value_type
TEMPLATE CLASS_Simple_types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliSense is not always right. In order to know everything about your code, it would have to fully compile it, but this would be too slow to be (conveniently) usable. Instead, it parses your code in a faster but less complete way to get autocompletion information and find obvious errors. However, sometimes it trips over something, either due to a bug or because it did not manage to obtain all the information it needs. When this happens, its output is not so (Intelli)sensible.

I would simply ignore the IntelliSense error, or, like you said, use `auto` instead of `item*` if you want to get rid of the error. Maybe in a later update, or after changes to your code, the error will magically disappear.